# Substitution of rowr function

Tags: r

I'm studying some projects in R and was faced with this situation

```
f <- rowr::rollApply(data = X, 
                     fun = function(x) {sum(x * k)},
                     window = n, minimum = n, align = "right")
```

The problem is that now there's no package called rowr.
By searching on the web, I found here on stackoverflow that the function

```
qpcR:::cbind.na
```

could substitute it very well, so I tried :

```
f <- qpcR:::cbind.na::rollApply(data = X, 
                     fun = function(x) {sum(x * k)},
                     window = n, minimum = n, align = "right")
```

but qpcR:::cbind.na only works with x and y parameters qpcR:::cbind.na(x,y), and in this case doesn't apply, any suggestions on how can I solve it?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rowr was removed from CRAN, see here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rowr/index.html

You can install an old version from the archive, to see if the code still works.

If it doesn't, then take a look at the 'rollapply' function from the 'zoo' package, it looks very similar to what the function you presented here is doing.

Comment: You're right mister @tester , found the rollapply function in the repository and it solved the problem, thanks a lot, best regards